# How to call event key_down only in specific situations in c#?

Tags: c#

I have 2 combo boxes and one text box(combo1, combo2, textBox). Here is the code for event key_down:

```
private void MyForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        buttonSearch_Click(sender, e);   
}
```

When I click button ENTER on keyboard I want that program call search button on form. The problem is when I select some item from combo box and click on ENTER to give me that item, he also call searh button, ofcource, but I dont want to call search until I fill both combo boxes and text box. So, I want to call search button ONLY when my focus is on text box. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: " I want to call search button ONLY when my focus is on text box" - so you could put the keydown event on the textbox?

Comment: Are you using winforms or wpf?

Comment: Yeah, I didnt know that the text box have event key down, didnt check it. I am new in this job, I now see that this was stupid question.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as said, you could put the event on the textbox.  Also, going with your original problem, you could check if the textbox has focus:

```
private void MyForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                if (textBox1.Focused) // or whatever your textbox is called
                {
                    buttonSearch_Click(sender, e);   
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have specific events for each control. You are using the Form events but if you only want to have the keydown when the Textbox is focussed I suggest the following:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        buttonSearch_Click(sender,e);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. NDJ replied immediately on my question, but I dont know if I can accept answer if he dont type some code... Tnx to all of you, I understand now.

Comment: Yeah, but I know from myself that I understand things more easily when I can see an example! :)